# How to filter out some specific rows from a PySpark dataframe depending on an interable (Set)?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I have a dataframe like this:

| FLAG | DATA |
| --- | --- |
| S | D1 |
| S | D2 |
| S | D3 |
| S | SP |
| N | D5 |
| N | D2 |
| N | D6 |
| N | SP |

Now I need to follow some instructions. They are:

1. Get dataframe where FLAG is S.
2. Get dataframe where FLAG is N.
3. On a new dataframe, first add all data from dataframe1 (data with FLAG S). Then, take only those rows from the dataframe2 (data with FLAG N), whose DATA value is not in dataframe1.
4. The only exception of point 3 is where DATA value is SP. If datafram2 has SP, it will be added to the new dataframe. For SP, no need to check the dataframe1 for addition.

Illustrations:

1. DataFrame 1

| FLAG | DATA |
| --- | --- |
| S | D1 |
| S | D2 |
| S | D3 |
| S | SP |

2. DataFrame 2

| FLAG | DATA |
| --- | --- |
| N | D5 |
| N | D2 |
| N | D6 |
| N | SP |

3. DataFrame 3

| FLAG | DATA |
| --- | --- |
| S | D1 |
| S | D2 |
| S | D3 |
| S | SP |
| N | D5 |
| N | D6 |
| N | SP |

N D2 is eliminated because DATA D2 is already present for FLAG S. But, SP is present for both N and S.

I tried this code snippet:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F    

all_data = final_df.select("FLAG", "DATA")
sf_DATA_set = set()
for data in all_data:
    if data["FLAG"] == 'S' and data["DATA"] != 'SP':
        sf_DATA_set.add(data["DATA"]) # Make a set of all DATA where FLAG is S except SP
    
df1 = final_df.filter("FLAG='S'")
df2 = final_df.filter("FLAG='N'")
   
df4 = df2.filter(~F.col("DATA").isin(tuple(sf_DATA_set)) # Getting only those fields from df2 whose DATA value isn't present in sf_DATA_set.
final_df = df4.unionByName(df1)
display(final_df.select(['FLAG', 'DATA']))
```

But this part isn't working properly.

```
df4 = df2.filter(~F.col("DATA").isin(tuple(sf_DATA_set))
```

How can I filter out the data from datafram2?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of `DATA` values where `FLAG == 'S'` and `DATA != 'SP'` and then filter those rows out by negating `.isin`

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def my_function(df):
  """
  Input: PySpark DataFrame
  Output: three PySpark DataFrames
  """
  
  df1 = df.filter(F.col('FLAG') == 'S')
  df2 = df.filter(F.col('FLAG') == 'N')
  
  # make a list of all DATA where FLAG is S except DATA is SP
  sf_data_list = all_data \
    .filter((F.col('FLAG') == 'S') & (F.col('DATA') != 'SP')) \
    .select('DATA') \
    .distinct() \
    .rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x) \
    .collect()
  
  df3 = df2 \
    .filter(~F.col('DATA').isin(sf_data_list)) \
    .unionByName(df1)
  
  return df1, df2, df3
```

#### Output

```
my_function(all_data)[2].show()

+----+----+
|FLAG|DATA|
+----+----+
|   N|  D5|
|   N|  D6|
|   N|  SP|
|   S|  D1|
|   S|  D2|
|   S|  D3|
|   S|  SP|
+----+----+
```

Comment: Thank you @Ric S. But can you tell me little bit about rdd.flatMap?

Comment: Since we want a list of values, we basically need to go to the structure underlying the dataframe (which is the RDD) and then collect values from there. If you want a few more examples, check out its [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.flatMap.html).